# Show inherited properties in agenda column view

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a 'meetings.org' file where I keep... er, my meetings.
Each heading is a specific subject, sub-headings (**) have a `time-stamp` and refer to specific meeting occurrences in the series:

```
* My favourite meeting
** <2018-09-11>
   something very important to discuss
```

I would like to visualise the name of the meeting when in the agenda view for the week. To this end, following what I understand of properties from [here](https://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html) and of `column-view` as explained [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html), I try to define an *inherited* property, by adding the suffix `_ALL` to the name of the property, like this:

```
* My favourite meeting
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Name_ALL:     CMOS Meeting
  :END:
** <2018-09-11>
   something very important to discuss
```

Also, at the top of the meetings file, I add the following:

```
#+COLUMNS: %30ITEM %20Name_ALL %TODO %3PRIORITY %TAGS
```

However, this does not lead to the visualisation of the property in the column view. The same procedure works if I either:

1 - define the property inside the sub-heading

2 - have a heading with the time-stamp itself and the property defined

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a variable to be set if one wants to turn inheritance on.
Inheritance is turned off by default, to avoid slowing down searches.
To turn inheritance on, set to `t` the `org--use-property-inheritance` variable.

See: https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! There is one more thing you (likely) need to do, and also one small mistake to fix.

First, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52279294/288545) is correct that you likely need to change the value of `org-use-property-inheritance` (since by default it is `nil`, which disables (most) property inheritance.

As for the second thing, I think you have (understandably) misunderstood the documentation that you linked. The property `PropertyName_All` is a special form that lets you pre-specify the allowable values for the property with name `PropertyName`. In effect, your setup is requiring that all of your `Name` values be either `CMOS` or `Meeting`. As an example of where you might want to use this, if you are going to classify all of your meetings as being either "Fun" or "Boring", you might set `MeetingType_All: Fun Boring`, and then when you use org mode tools to set properties in child nodes, you will get some autocompletion help and other goodies to quickly choose between either "Fun" or "Boring". `MeetingType_All` is *itself* a property, and in fact it is a special property that will be inherited by its descendants regardless of the value of `org-use-property-inheritance` (this is the sense of "inheritance" that the [guide you linked to](https://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html) is discussing).

Here is an edited version of your file that will both turn on property inheritance (just for the `Name` property) and will do so just for the current file using [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html): when you open it in emacs, it will ask if you want to actually set the values which is a safeguard against malicious code being snuck in via file local variables.

If you want inheritance to work everywhere, you can customize the value of the variable `org-use-property-inheritance` globally.
Probably the easiest way to do this is by typing `M-x customize RET`, then search for `org-use-property-inheritance`, and use the interface to change the value and potentially make it persist across emacs sessions.

If you turn on column view for this file, you should see "CMOS Meeting" appropriately inherited for the child entry.

```
#+COLUMNS: %30ITEM %20Name %TODO %3PRIORITY %TAGS
* My favourite meeting
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Name:     CMOS Meeting
  :END:
** <2018-09-11>
   something very important to discuss
# Local Variables:
# org-use-property-inheritance: ("Name")
# End:
```